# What is the purpose of --file-type in ls command

Tags: ls

I'm trying to understand the purpose of the `--file-type` argument of the UNIX `ls` command.

I didn't find any example using `ls --file-type` on the web – neither was I able to make sense of the `--file-type` argument by issuing `ls --file-type` myself.

What's the purpose of `ls --file-type`? Would anyone please give me a helpful example of `ls --file-type` making the purpose of this argument more clear to me?

Comment: ***likewise, except do not append '*'*** .... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from `info ls`:

> `-F`
>
> Append a character to each file name indicating the file type.
>   Also, for regular files that are executable, append `*`.  The file
>   type indicators are `/` for directories, `@` for symbolic links,
>   `|` for FIFOs, `=` for sockets, `>` for doors, and nothing for
>        regular files.

`--file-type` is just like `-F`, except that it doesn't append `*` for executable files:

```
$ ln -s /etc/passwd foo
$ touch bar; chmod +x bar
$ ls
foo  bar
$ ls -F
foo@  bar*
$ ls --file-type
foo@  bar
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The `--file-type` option is similar to the `-F` option.

```
-F, --classify
   append indicator (one of */=>@|) to entries

--file-type
   likewise, except do not append `*'
```

[Source](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/ls.1.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of `ls --file-tye /`

```
bin@  boot/  dev/  etc/  home/  lib@  lib64@  lost+found/  media/  mnt/  opt/  proc/  root/  run/  sbin@  srv/  sys/  tmp/  usr/  var/
```

as compared to the output of `ls -l /`

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root      7 Jan 19 02:32 bin -> usr/bin
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root   4096 Jan  1  1970 boot
drwxr-xr-x  24 root root   4220 Mar 26 19:56 dev
drwxr-xr-x  88 root root   4096 Mar 26 21:15 etc
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root   4096 Apr  5  2020 home
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root      7 Jan 19 02:32 lib -> usr/lib
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root      7 Jan 19 02:32 lib64 -> usr/lib
drwx------   2 root root  16384 Apr  5  2020 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root   4096 Dec 11 20:19 media
drwxr-xr-x   7 root root  4096 Sep  8  2020  mnt
drwxr-xr-x   9 root root   4096 Feb  9 13:58 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 335 root root      0 Mar 26 19:56 proc
drwxr-x---   9 root root   4096 Feb 11 13:18 root
drwxr-xr-x  28 root root    700 Mar 26 21:15 run
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root      7 Jan 19 02:32 sbin -> usr/bin
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root   4096 Apr  5  2020 srv
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root      0 Mar 26 19:56 sys
drwxrwxrwt  12 root root    320 Mar 26 22:11 tmp
drwxr-xr-x   9 root root   4096 Mar 25 11:06 usr
drwxr-xr-x  12 root root   4096 Mar 25 11:07 var
```

As you see the symbol "`@`" indicates symbolic-links (`l`). Directories (`d`) and regular files (`f`) are not flagged by the `--file-type` argument.

Issuing `ls --file-type` in my home directory is identical to `ls ~` since it only contains directories and regular files and hence the output of the former doesn't contain any indicators.

See also the answer of [PesaThe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6529322/simon-clark) for a full list of the indicator symbols.